# kubectl top node cannot work, it shows: "error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)"

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to demploy a k8s environment for ver1.12_rc.1.
It includes one master and 2 nodes. All of them are CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core). The related info are follows:

```
[root@bogon174 dashboard]# kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                     READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
heapster-684777c4cb-fm6kd                1/1     Running   0          32m
kubernetes-dashboard-77fd78f978-khc4f    1/1     Running   0          32m
metrics-server-v0.3.1-6879897646-c7rwz   2/2     Running   0          37m
monitoring-grafana-56b668bccf-29277      1/1     Running   0          32m
monitoring-influxdb-5c5bf4949d-l8ttc     1/1     Running   0          32m

[root@bogon174 dashboard]# kubectl get services -n kube-system
NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)         AGE
heapster               ClusterIP   169.169.120.140   <none>        80/TCP          33m
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort    169.169.151.109   <none>        443:26007/TCP   33m
metrics-server         NodePort    169.169.218.252   <none>        443:10521/TCP   38m
monitoring-grafana     ClusterIP   169.169.170.53    <none>        80/TCP          33m
monitoring-influxdb    ClusterIP   169.169.248.0     <none>        8086/TCP        33m

[root@bogon174 dashboard]# kubectl get nodes
NAME             STATUS     ROLES    AGE   VERSION
192.168.20.171   Ready      <none>   10d   v1.12.0-rc.1
192.168.20.172   NotReady   <none>   10d   v1.12.0-rc.1
```

[image]

I researched previous questions, but I cannot to get the correct solution.

Comment: Could be you're hitting https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/58 maybe?

Comment: I will try to rebuild those ca files according to this issue case.

Comment: why is your second node in not ready state

Comment: @eric_zhang, Where is your master node located?

Comment: @Shashank:
  I stopped kubectl and kube-proxy services in the second node temporarily , I just wanted that all the servies were run in one node.

Comment: @mk_sta: 
  master server is 192.168.20.174, node servers are 171~172

Answer (score 3):

For my friends on EKS make sure you have the username set (and not set to just the session name like I did):

```
robert ❱ kubectl get configmaps -n kube-system aws-auth -o yaml | grep MyTeamRole$ -A 3
- rolearn: arn:aws:iam::123546789012:role/MyTeamRole
  username: {{SessionName}}
  groups:
    - system:masters
robert ❱ kubectl top node
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
robert ❱ 1 ❱ kubectl edit configmap -n kube-system aws-auth
configmap/aws-auth edited
robert ❱ kubectl get configmaps -n kube-system aws-auth -o yaml | grep MyTeamRole$ -A 3
    - rolearn: arn:aws:iam::123546789012:role/MyTeamRole
      username: literally_anything:{{SessionName}}
      groups:
        - system:masters
robert ❱ kubectl top node
NAME                                       CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
ip-10-0-3-103.us-west-2.compute.internal   341m         17%    1738Mi          52%
...
robert ❱ kubectl logs -n kube-system -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=metrics-server
E0407 22:34:45.879156       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:34:49.399854       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:34:50.691133       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:34:51.827629       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:39:07.288163       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:39:08.755492       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:39:09.801957       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:40:32.405458       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=801591513699736721, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:43:09.791769       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
E0407 22:44:14.244221       1 authentication.go:63] "Unable to authenticate the request" err="verifying certificate SN=3949940469908359789, SKID=, AKID= failed: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"
robert ❱
```

Comment: works, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Version 1.12 is no longer using heapster , and the top command is not yet ported to the new metrics system. There is a github issue for that  , in order for the top to work with new metrics system.

Look at the options available , the only one is heapster but heapster is no more used.

```
[iahmad@web-prod-ijaz001 ~]$ kubectl top node --help
Display Resource (CPU/Memory/Storage) usage of nodes. 

The top-node command allows you to see the resource consumption of nodes.

Aliases:
node, nodes, no

Examples:
  # Show metrics for all nodes
  kubectl top node

  # Show metrics for a given node
  kubectl top node NODE_NAME

Options:
      --heapster-namespace='kube-system': Namespace Heapster service is located in
      --heapster-port='': Port name in service to use
      --heapster-scheme='http': Scheme (http or https) to connect to Heapster as
      --heapster-service='heapster': Name of Heapster service
  -l, --selector='': Selector (label query) to filter on, supports '=', '==', and '!='.(e.g. -l key1=value1,key2=value2)

Usage:
  kubectl top node [NAME | -l label] [options]
```

Comment: According your explain, if I want to get CPU/Memory/Storage's resource values, I have to deploy a lower version, less than v1.12, for example, v1.11 or 1.10 ?
  so far, it's unvavliable in v1.12?